# Перевод из римских чисел в численные

Tags: python

Яндекс контест задача Е римлянин. https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/36783/problems/E/

Вам дано число, записанное римскими цифрами. Получите это же число в обычной записи (арабскими цифрами).
Римская запись чисел может включать следующие символы:

’I’ — 1

’V’ — 5

’X’ — 10

’L’ — 50

’C’ — 100

’D’ — 500

’M’ — 1000

Цифры ’I’, ’X’, ’C’ и ’M’ нельзя использовать более трех раз подряд. Цифры ’V’, ’L’ и ’D’ нельзя использовать более одного раза во всей записи числа.
Обыкновенно цифры записывают по убыванию слева направо. Например, число 350 будет записано как ’CCCL’.
Однако есть исключения:

Чтобы получить ’4’ или ’9’, надо поставить ’I’ перед ’V’ или ’X’ соответственно
Чтобы получить ’40’ или ’90’, надо поставить ’X’ перед ’L’ или ’C’.
Чтобы получить ’400’ или ’900’, надо поставить ’C’ перед ’D’ или ’M’.
Вы можете воспользоваться заготовками кода для данной задачи из репозитория курса.

Формат ввода
В единственной строке дана запись числа римскими цифрами. Длина записи не превосходит 15.
Формат вывода
Выведите число, записанное арабскими цифрами. Если запись числа некорректная, то выведите -1.

### Пример 1
Ввод    Вывод
VIV

Пример 2
Ввод    Вывод
II
2

Пример 3
Ввод    Вывод
MCMLXI
1961

Моё решение проходит 21 тест и частично зеленое - почти решил. не знаю, как пройти 21 тест.

```py
from collections import Counter

    def convert_to_arabic(number: str) -> int:
   
        c = dict(Counter(number))
        for k,v in c.items():
            if k in ['V' , "L", 'D']:
                if v >1:
                    return -1
        if 'XXXX' in number or 'IIII' in number or 'CCCC' in number or 'MMMM' in number:
            return -1
        d = dict()
        d['I'] = 1
        d['V'] = 5
        d['X'] = 10
        d['L'] = 50
        d['C'] = 100
        d['D'] = 500
        d['M'] = 1000
        good = ['IV','IX', 'XL', 'XC', 'CD', 'CM']
        if len(number) == 0 or number == ' ':
            return 0
    
        res = 0
        for i in range(len(number)):
            if i < len(number)-1 and d[number[i]] < d[number[i+1]]:
                check = number[i:i+2]
                if check not in good:
                    return -1
                res -= d[number[i]]
            else:
                res += d[number[i]]
        return res
    
    roman_number = input()
    print(convert_to_arabic(roman_number))
```

Comment: На всякий случай - мы не видим задачу.

Comment: @MBo блин сорри добавил ))

Comment: А римские числа - какие-то не *численные*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка *IIV* не является римским числом, но ваш код считает что это число *5*. Некоторые другие некорректные строки тоже пропускаются. Других ошибок тестирование не выявило.

Другой подход подход состоит в том чтобы выписать все возможные римские цифры и искать их в числе последовательно от старших к младшим:

```
#    0    1     2      3     4    5     6      7       8     9
romans = (
    ('', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX'),  # *    1
    ('', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC'),  # *   10
    ('', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CD', 'D', 'DC', 'DCC', 'DCCC', 'CM'),  # *  100
    ('', 'M', 'MM', 'MMM'                                      )   # * 1000
)


def make_match(p, chunks):
    m = sorted(
        ((c, i * 10 ** p) for i, c in enumerate(chunks)),
        key=lambda p: len(p[0]),
        reverse=True
    )

    def match(s, i):
        for c, v in m:
            if s.startswith(c, i):
                return v, i + len(c)

    return match


matches = tuple(make_match(*p) for p in enumerate(romans))[::-1]


def read_roman(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return -1
    n = 0
    i = 0
    for m in matches:
        v, i = m(s, i)
        n += v
    return n if i == len(s) else -1


print(read_roman(input()))
```

Можно проверить и разобрать римское число регулярным выражением. Алгоритм в основном тот же:

```
import re

romans = (
    {c: i for i, c in enumerate(tokens.split(' '))}
    for tokens in (
#       0 1  2   3  4 5  6   7    8  9
        ' I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX',  # *    1
        ' X XX XXX XL L LX LXX LXXX XC',  # *   10
        ' C CC CCC CD D DC DCC DCCC CM',  # *  100
        ' M MM MMM'                       # * 1000
    )
)

m = re.match(
    '(M{0,3})' +
    '(DC{0,3}|C[DM]|C{0,3})' +
    '(LX{0,3}|X[LC]|X{0,3})' + 
    '(VI{0,3}|I[VX]|I{0,3})$',
    input()
)
if m is None:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(sum(
        r[g] * 10 ** i
        for i, (g, r) in enumerate(zip(reversed(m.groups()), romans))
    ))
```

Comment: спс вопрос "тестирование не выявило" - у меня всегда было с этим не оч. не все тест кейсы в голове могу придумать )) вобще не думал про запись наоборот iiv

Comment: Тестировались все последовательности символов длиной от 1 до 9. Сравнивались результаты вашей функции и моей. Для правильных чисел все совпало, для не правильных полезли ошибки. Такое тестирование можно устроить и без второго алгоритма, если есть печать римского числа по арабскому, что написать значительно проще.